# How to access views created in the database using frappe

Tags: database, mariadb, erpnext, frappe, database-view

We have created a view in the mariadb. We want to access that view from Frappe. Does frappe supports this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query report which pulls data from your view. Then you can examine the data in the report view.

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 13, Frappe Framework only supports schema managed by DocTypes. Views are not supported.